# Can't open file to write

Tags: linux, permissions, raspberry-pi

I am using the Raspberry Pi 3. I want to modify the file (increase the limit of files) `limits.conf` in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, but when I try to save the file after modification, it gives the error `[Can't open file to write]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the file `limits.conf` is only writable as the root user, you must launch `nano` as root using `sudo`. For example:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/security/limits.conf
```